# android.hardware.camera2 ERROR CAMERA IN USE

Tags: android-mediarecorder, android-camera2

I'm using the google sample 'android-Camera2Video':

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

The problem is that when the app is finishing the recording, sometimes it stucks for a moment, and then calls the **onError()** handler of the **CameraDevice.StateCallback** with 1 - '**ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE**' error code.

It does not happen every single time, it happens in about 90% of cases, and sometimes everything works fine with no errors. I couldn't find out on what it depends and how to resolve this issue. If anyone have met this problem before, please help.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I use old version api.

Comment: I meet same problem. Has anybody can find a solution?